# Update single Item row in dynamoDB BOTO3

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Trying to update single Item row in dynamoDB table. Scenario is I'm getting values from api gateway request to update in dynamodb table via lambda.
Request for lambda is like:

```
'attribute':['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', ....], 'value':['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', ....]
```

What I tried is merged this two lists as dictionary. eg:

```
col_header = response['attribute']
values = ['value']
data = dict(zip(col_header, values))
```

trying to use this code available in [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.UpdateItem.html) but having issues on how to use created dictionary in UpdateExpression and ExpressionAttributeValues.

for eg:

```
UpdateExpression="set {1}".format(','.join(f'{x}' for x in col_header))
```

but if I use this way, then I'm not getting how I pass '=:r' with every attribute and then same for ExpressionAttributeValues as shown in [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.UpdateItem.html).

```
UpdateExpression="set info.rating=:r, info.plot=:p",
ExpressionAttributeValues={
                    ':r': Decimal(str(rating)), ':p': plot},
```

Code I tried is:

```
update_value_placeholder = [f":val{i}" for i in range(len(column_header))]

update_expression, .join('set (= {}'.format(i) for i in zip(column_header, update_value_placeholder))
expression_attr = dict(zip(update_value_placeholder, values))

try:

  response = self.table.update_item(

  Key={'CreateTimeStamp': partition_key, 'sort_key_attr': pk}, 
  UpdateExpression = update_expression,
  ExpressionAttributeValues = expression_attr,
  ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW")
except Exception as e:
    return str(e)
```

But with this approach the issue is in my tables i have partition key which is set to creattimestamp and I don't have any way to find particular item timestamp.
If there is any approach in which I can update table only by sort key that will be great.

Comment: "having issues " - what issues? You haven't provided any code demonstrating those issues nor any error messages.

Comment: @Marcin sorry for confusion, added sample code in question, with documentation example that I want to achieve.

Comment: Do you set the `ExpressionAttributeNames` parameter?

Comment: @Vlad Holubiev yes I tried it, I have updated my question with the complete approach